# Join Tables with date range

Tags: sql, date, join, group-by

I have 2 tables that I am trying to join. But also adding in date range. How can I do this?
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not as images.

Answer (score 1):

One reasonable option would be a correlated subquery:

```
select 
    t1.*,
    (
        select sum(t2.new_users)
        from table_2
        where 
            t2.campaignid = t1.campaignid 
            and t2.date between t1.sentdate and t1.enddate
    ) new_users
from table_1 t1
```

Answer (score 0):

A join and aggregation will do:

```
select
  a.sentdate, a.enddate, a.campaignid, a.sent,
  sum(b.New_Users) as New_Users
from table1 a
join table2 b on b.date >= a.sentdate and b.date <= a.enddate
             and b.campaignid = a.campaignid
group by a.sentdate, a.enddate, a.campaignid, a.sent
```